# MATLAB: Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type when accessing a cell column

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am extracting data from a table and storing the 1*1 cursor in curs.

The code is something like this:

```
curs = exec(conn,['Select D***V***e,D***T***S***p From ' **** ' where Attribute = "****"']);
    curs = fetch(curs);
    Data = curs.Data;
    close(curs);
s = string(Data.D***T***S***p);
```

This gives me the error | | | Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type. Error in WaveletCode (line 11) s = string(Data.DataTimeStamp);|||

The Data is a 30000*2 cell in below format

```
84.3363037100000    '2017-06-01T00:00:03.5+10:00'
99.5158004800000    '2017-06-01T00:01:03.5+10:00'
```

Can someone help me figure out what is he issue with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is a cell array with DataValues in column one and DataTimeStamp in column two. Cell arrays can contain any data type (string, arrays, structure, function handles...), but some conversions can be done on cell arrays with a consistent type across the array.
Read documentation on `cell` data type for more information.

e.g.

```
%Select first column (cell array of scalars) and convert to array
Value = cell2mat(Data(:,1));
%Select second column (cell array of char) and convert to a string array
TimeStamp = string(Data(:,2));
```